# What's the mounted path for sound device?

Tags: sound, input-devices, output

As the title?

In red hat sound device is mounted at /dev/dsp. How about ubuntu?

Regards,
Hua Jie

Answer (score 0):

The device files for sound devices are located at `/dev/snd/`

Btw.: It seems you're mixing up the expressions *mountpoint* and *device file*. That's a great difference

Comment: While what's the different between them. There are many files under /dev/snd which one is the sound device?